# When does dashing through shots actually work?

Tags: hyper-light-drifter

One of the upgrades for the blink or dash ability in Hyper Light Drifter seems to be that you can block projectile attacks while dashing.  The shop advertisement shows your character with several projectiles coming at them, then he dashes and a diamond barrier shows up and blocks the shots.

In practice though, it seems completely random when the barrier *actually* appears.  I've been able to use it successfully a few times, but never whenever it actually matters.  This is really frustrating since I feel like I could have spent my upgrade points on something that I will consistently benefit from.

How does the blink barrier actually work?  When does it show up, when does it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can only dash through bullets when bullets are right next to you.  A barrier outline will appear around your character when you are able to to the barrier dash indicating that the ability will trigger.

Take a look at the screenshot below to see the ability indication:

[image: Dash Barrier Indication]

Here's an animation of the indicator popping up several times in a row:

[image: Dash Barrier Indicator animation]